# Add new child instance in Grails

Tags: grails

Whats the best practice to add another instance of child in grails?

If i have this domains

```
class Parent {
   String name
   static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

class Child {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}
```

Do I manually get the ID of parent and store it to the child instance if I want to create a new child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Parent parent = Parent.get(parentId)

Child child = new Child(
    parent: parent, 
    name: 'name'
)

child.save()
parent.addToChildren(child)
parent.save()
```

or...

```
Parent parent = Parent.get(parentId)
Child child = new Child()
child.name = 'name'
child.parent = parent
child.save()
parent.addToChildren(child)
parent.save()
```

Comment: What if child doesn't only have name as its attribute(don't know if this is the term in grails) what if it has 10 attributes, I just have to add inside the parenthesis? doesn't that make the code look ugly?

Comment: You can either add the extra parameters in the constructor or you can create a new instance of `Child` and then set them on that instance as shown above. Either way works, up to you which you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The code of rcgeorge is valid but you don't need to save the child before using the addTo method, because it will be saved by cascade. So...

```
Parent parent = Parent.get(parentId)

Child child = new Child(
    parent: parent, 
    name: 'name'
)

parent.addToChildren(child)
parent.save()
```